# The source code isn't shown in debugger window in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

My Xcode always show me the ASM code of my source code file in the view of the debugger even  I have the source code file.  And I also do not know how to fix the problem.  Can you help me.?
Version is 4.3.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849181/why-is-my-xcode-4-2-log-always-empty/7849807#7849807

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck in Xcode menu Product:Debug Workflow:Show Disassembly While Debugging

[image]