# How does the UIButton @selector works?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, selector

I'm pretty new at iOS dev, and I wonder how works this line :

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I simply tried this :

```
- (void) doSomething : (id) sender
{
   NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does your code have a space in between `doSomething` and the colon, or is that a typo? If it's intentional then the selector needs to be `doSomething:`.

Comment: I tried both, but it doesn't work.
Wait... is it wrong if I declared my button in my UIViewController instead of my UIView (programatically) ?

Comment: what doesn't work? It should print `Test` in the log when you tap it(and release inside the button)

Comment: @Novarg That's what doesn't work, it doesn't print it in the log

Comment: @RobinDreux Having the space before the colon in the selector name guarantees that it definitely won't work.

Comment: @RobinDreux are you using xib to make a button? If so, are you sure that it's connected to the corresponding IBOutlet?

Comment: Make sure that the addTarget portion is actually being called (i.e. put a breakpoint there).  Often times I put this stuff in the wrong location and it never gets called.

Comment: @JohnTopley I tried without this space and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @Novarg I'm almost sure I'm missing something. For the moment I've created a UIView class "InfosView", declared my button and the doSomething function into it. In IB I've created a ViewController, set the class of its view to InfosView, and linked my button to the UIButton. I'm sure I'm missing something..

Comment: Just to double check that the following is not the case... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849181/why-is-my-xcode-4-2-log-always-empty/7849807#7849807

Comment: @RobinDreux where is that `addTarget` line of code? Post more code please if you don't mind

Comment: @RobinDreux and a small screenshot with the connections in the xib

Comment: Thanks @Luke, but no problem with that ;)

Comment: @Novarg I must also add a line code for addTarget ? Every tutorial I've watched only says to add the code portions I shown in my first post...

Comment: @RobinDreux no, I mean where does the line `[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` stand? In which method?

Comment: It's in the initWithFrame method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

.h file has

```
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

in .xib link the button with myButton (i.e. image)

Comment: Please, what is the line I must add in my .h file to see "actionMyButton:" in .xib ?

Comment: You don't need **actionMyButton**. You have **doSomething** in .m added in .m file

Comment: Yes of course, but I guess I've to link my Touch Up Inside to my doSomething: method, right ?

Comment: From new reference outlet right circle drag N drop it on file's owner. You should see myButton click on it. Thats all

Comment: You have linked **doSomething** with UIControlEventTouchUpInside in .m file

Answer (score 5):

Try below like as code this is work for me:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and tried this

```
-(void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

Welcome!

Comment: Thanks for this advice, but it still doesn't work for me. I almost sure this issue doesn't concern the code but my connections in IB...

Comment: ok you right click the button in designview on xib file and check reference outlet and touch up inside event is mentioned or not!

Comment: @Dinesh the touchUpInside event is not needed if you would use the way that you showed

Comment: You're right... the outlet is mentioned, not the touch up inside. To what do I have to link it ?

Comment: you have touchUpinside click the plus symbol and drag to the your view controller header file and mentioned the event function name and click ok now created event,check event is called or not!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your advices. It was a really noobish problem, but I'm improving little by little :)